# How to get location in background of button c#

Tags: windows, xaml, button, location

I have a button in xaml like this

```
<button>
  <button.background>
    <imagebrush imagesource="/Assets/Image1xxx.png"/>
  </button.background>
</button>
```

But now in code behind(cs) how can I get string "Assets/Image1xxx.png" from any event. help me. I am trying with button_name.Background.ImageBrush.Uri(), now working

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the imagesource. This is a BitmapImage. Than you can get the UriSource which will be your imagesource of the imagebrush. Try something like this:

```
    <Button Tapped="SimpleButton_Tapped">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/SmallLogo.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

And in the code behind:

```
  private void SimpleButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            ImageBrush imageBrush = button.Background as ImageBrush;
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/otherIcon.png"));
            imageBrush.ImageSource = image;

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = imageBrush.ImageSource as BitmapImage;
            String imageSource = bitmapImage.UriSource + "";
            Debug.WriteLine("The new imageSource of the button is: " + imageSource);
        }
    }
```

This will get you the following output:

ImageSource : ms-appx:/Assets/otherIcon.png

Comment: But i dont define name x:Name="BtnImageSource", because i have many button, i want set up 1 event to all button, to change background for that button

Comment: I changed the code that it should work foreach of your buttons

Comment: ok i  agree, but wrong with me, now i have 4 button, i want have a event for all, and inside if (thisbutton.background.image==image1)
image=image2
else image = image1. You stand by me ?